# How to add a column of hyperlink within dash datatable and the URL where the user is redirected is dependent on the row being clicked?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm using dash_table.DataTable in python plotly-dash application. Currently I have implemented the following:

1. The first column of the table is 'itemID.'
2. The last column of the table is 'detail' and its data is clickable.
3. Clicking on the data redirects the user to another page that shows the detail of the item.
4. The URL where the user is redirected is dependent on the row being clicked. Hence each link has a unique URL.

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with the `DataTable`. To do so, you need buttons or `a` tags embedded in the cells, which that table won't like. You could do this with an `html.Table` component, though. You'd have to build it a little more by hand, likely using loops, but it's very doable. A short example:

```py
html.Table([
    html.Body([
        html.Tr([
            html.Td(html.A('Click this link', id='my-link-1', href='www.some_site.com')),
            html.Td(123),
        ])
    ])
])
```